# Amplifier Current Noise Imaginary Impedance

Tags: current, noise

Does the current noise spec of an amplifier need to be multiplied by only the real R component of impedance on it's input or the total impedance? Would increasingly larger inline capacitor values result in higher output voltage noise (current noise transformation through C)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Noise gets converted to voltage with Impedance so low impedance translates into lower effects of current noise.  U(f) = I(f) * Z(f)   ( or V=IR)

Thus devices with high current noise and low voltage noise (BJT's) are better suited to low Z designs. and low current noise (FETs) but with high voltage noise are better suited for high impedance and high voltage circuits.  See Ref*

- More info on Noise https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-047.pdf

Comment: So it is both the real and imaginary impedance that contribute to noise? Not just real?

Comment: @EasyOhm The real part generates noise by itself, but it is the complex impedance that generates noise when a noise current passes through it